# Create a qrcode image then convert to base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, qr-code

I am using http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ to generate qr-code

```js
          var qrcode = new QRCode("qrcode", {
            text: "http://jindo.dev.naver.com/collie",
            width: 128,
            height: 128,
            colorDark: "#000000",
            colorLight: "#ffffff",
            correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
          });
          console.log(qrcode);
          console.log(qrcode._el.children[1].currentSrc);
```

[image]

I can find the base64 code in "qrcode"
But why I get empty when I run:

```
console.log(qrcode._el.children[1].currentSrc);
```

[image]

Is there any other method to get the base64 code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    const base64String = document.querySelector("#qrcode img").src;
});
```

The reason for that is that it simply runs async and needs some time to be set to the image attribute.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I have a question that why "console.log(qrcode)" can display item but console.log(qrcode._el.children[1].currentSrc) cannot display item?

Comment: For the same reason, you can put it into setTimeout and it will work.
Console prints a link to your variable qrcode, so whenever anything changes inside of that object will be reflected in DevTools.
So, by the time you're checking the qrcode._el.children[1].currentSrc it is already filled in.

I would not recommend you to use private API of the library as it may change anytime.